# send SSE only to specific clients using flask

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events

[flask-sse](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-sse) provides some example code in its [quickstart](https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) section. However that code publishes events to all subscribed clients. To publish events to only some clients, the documentation suggests using channels. However, what if those events must be private (for example notifications that a new message has arrived for a specific user)? You don't want to do something like have a client pass a user ID, and for the server to push updates on the channel named after that user ID, because that presents a security/privacy issue.

What's the right way, if any, to implement such functionality with `flask_sse` or simply `flask`?

For example, a user can pass its `JWT` to the subscription API endpoint. But then what?

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_jwt_extended import current_user, jwt_required
from flask_sse import sse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/subscribe")
@jwt_required()
def subscribe():
    ....?


@app.route("/receive-message")
def receive_message():
    # message comes in for a user from outside the system
    # for example this API is triggered by a webhook from a third party service

    form_data = request.json()
    # figure out who the recipient is
    user_uuid = get_destination_user_id(form_data)
    user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(uuid=user_uuid).one()

    # now we want to publish an event, but only for this user...
    ...?
```